# How to write the given query in hibernate using create Query

Tags: hibernate

```
select tbl_LanguageData.Name As defaultLabel,
       IsNull((Select Top 1  LanguageInfo From tbl_Language_TranslationInfo 
               Where tbl_Language_TranslationInfo.Languageid = 48 
               And tbl_Language_TranslationInfo.LanguageDataId = tbl_LanguageData.LanguageDataId), 
       tbl_LanguageData.Name) As localLang
from tbl_UILabels, tbl_LanguageData
Where tbl_UILabels.LanguageDataId = tbl_LanguageData.LanguageDataId 
  And menuid = 10100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already define your persistence unit ( file persistence.xml in repository META-INF), you can use the entity manager and the createNativeQuery method

```
//declare the entity manager

EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("name of your persistence unit").createEntityManager();

String request = "your request";

Result result = em.createNativeQuery(request,Result.class).getResultList();
```